# Help me understand notation

Tags: calculus

[image]

Note: The inverse of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$.

My interpretation of this: $1$ is equal to the derivative of $x$ which is equal to the derivative of the inverse function.

Then this next part is where it gets foggy for me...

The derivative of the inverse with respect to x is the function times its derivative...? But I just said what the derivative of the inverse was before...? Why is chain rule used here?

I assume the first part bottom line is because the functions derivative is $1$ but why does that become $\frac{1}{f'(x)}?$

If anyone's wondering, I am using this to prove the derivative of arcsin, but I would like as little help as possible, I just want to understand the problem is all, not a full solve. Thanks.

Comment: I've just updated my answer to show how the Leibniz notation makes it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My interpretation of this: $1$ is equal to the derivative of $x$ which is equal to the derivative of the inverse function.

That is incorrect.
$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))$$
is the derivative of ***the function $f^{-1}$*** ***applied to the function $f$***. For comparison, the derivative of the inverse function is
$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x).$$
Note that a different way of writing would be
$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(f^{-1}\circ f)(x),$$
where $\circ$ denotes the composition of two functions. The fact that we have two functions being composed means that we should use the chain rule ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)), which is precisely what occurs in the rest of the equations you are asking about.

---

**The main confusion here is that the juxtaposition of two symbols can mean two different things: multiplication of two functions, and application of a function (or operation) to an input.**

In the expression
$$\frac{d}{dx}x$$
we apply the operation $\frac{d}{dx}$ to the function $x\mapsto x$ to produce the (constant) function $x\mapsto 1$.

In the expression
$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))$$
we apply the operation $\frac{d}{dx}$ to the function $x\mapsto f^{-1}(f(x))$. Since $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for every $x$ (by the very definition of $f^{-1}$ being the inverse of $f$), that's why we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}x=\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x)).$$

In the expression
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x))f'(x)$$
we are **multiplying** two functions, $x\mapsto\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x))$ and $x\mapsto f'(x)$.

(Remember, to multiply two functions $x\mapsto g(x)$ and $x\mapsto h(x)$, we send each $x$ to the product of their two values, making the function $x\mapsto g(x)\cdot h(x)$.)

In the expression
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x)),$$
the symbols $\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}$ denote the **function that is the derivative of $f^{-1}$**, and we are plugging in the value $f(x)$ to this function. Thus,
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x))$$
is **the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at the point $f(x)$** (just like the derivative of $x^2$ at the point $3$ is $6$).

The symbol $f'(x)$ is of course another way of writing **the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$**, i.e.
$$f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}(x).$$

Comment: Thanks. That was a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply by the chain rule you have the third equality and then you deduce the expression of the derivative  $(f^{-1})'(f(x))$ by division.

Answer (score 1):

See $f^{-1}(f(x))$ as a function with argument $f(x)$. Than, if you want to find $df^{-1}(f(x))/dx$ you must use the chain rule, i.e. $df^{-1}(f(x))/dx=[df^{-1}(f(x))/df(x)]*[df(x)/dx]$.

Than from $1=df^{-1}(f(x))/dx * f'(x)$ we have that $df^{-1}(f(x))/dx=1/f'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule is used when you differentiate a function of a function of $x$, when $x$ is the variable with respect to which you're differentiating.  That's what you got where you see $\dfrac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))$.

$$
1 = \dfrac{d}{dx} x = \frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(f(x)) = {f^{-1}}^\prime (f(x))\cdot f'(x).
$$

Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{f^{\,\prime}(x)} = {f^{-1}}^\prime(f(x)).
$$

I'd go on from there to write

$$
\frac{1}{f^{\,\prime}(f^{-1}(y))} = {f^{-1}}^\prime (y).
$$

That tells you how to differentiate inverse functions and shows you how that comes from the chain rule.

Here's how I would present it.  The chain rule can be stated as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}.
$$
That treats $du$ as if it were literally a number.  So
$$
1 = \frac{dw}{dw} = \frac{dw}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dw}.
$$
Therefore
$$ {f^{-1}}^\prime(x) = \frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{1}{dx/dw} = \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dw}f(w)} = \frac{1}{f^\prime(w)} = \frac{1}{f^\prime(f^{-1}(x))}.$$